Docker compose DB not reachable from .NET 8 + Entity Framework
I have not managed to connect to my docker Postgres image and its corresponding DB from my .NET 8 application using entity framework both specified and started up with the same docker-compose.yml.
Detail - working tree:
.net8 console application working tree
./Docker-compose.yml:
services:
  ausgabenapp:
    image: ausgabenapp
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
  
  postgres.ausgaben:
    image: postgres:latest
    ports: 
      - 5432:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: user 
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: password
      POSTGRES_DB: ausgaben_db
    volumes:
      - ${PWD}/db-data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data/

The connection string used in .NET 8 with Entity.FrameworkCore Nuget packages:
Npgsql.Entity.FrameworkCore.PostreSQL
Microsoft Extensions.Hosting 

is installed:
var con = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString: "Host = postgres.ausgaben; Port=5432;User Id=user; Password=password;Database=ausgaben_db;");

Docker containers terminal output
`[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Container ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  Created                                                                                                                                           0.1s 
 ✔ Container ausgabenapp-ausgabenapp-1        Created                                                                                                                                           0.0s 

ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.647 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 16.4 (Debian 16.4-1.pgdg120+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 12.2.0-14) 12.2.0, 64-bit
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.648 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.648 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.653 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.678 UTC [65] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-24 15:59:04 UTC
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.702 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 16:04:04.765 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint starting: time
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 16:04:08.865 UTC [63] LOG:  checkpoint complete: wrote 43 buffers (0.3%); 0 WAL file(s) added, 0 removed, 0 recycled; write=4.063 s, sync=0.013 s, total=4.101 s; sync files=12, longest=0.006 s, average=0.002 s; distance=250 kB, estimate=250 kB; lsn=0/1950998, redo lsn=0/1950960

Error message:
when calling con.Open() on the NpgsqlConnection in debug mode, I get the following error:

System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (00000005, 0xFFFDFFFF): nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Question
How do I connect my .NET 8 application running Entity Framework to my database, both running in containers spun up with the assist of docker compose?
My understanding
To me it seems that the I have a misunderstanding of the connections string Host, which I specified as "postgres.ausgaben" which is also the name of the spinned up service in the compose file.
Postgres Docu:
Doku
Specifies the host to be:

Specifies the host name - and optionally port - on which PostgreSQL is running. Multiple hosts may be specified, see the docs for more info. If the value begins with a slash, it is used as the directory for the Unix-domain socket (specifying a Port is still required).

I also do not quiet understand this LOG from the above spin up terminal output:
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.678 UTC [65] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2024-08-24 15:59:04 UTC
ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1  | 2024-08-24 15:59:04.702 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections

I tried

Different Host paths such as just ausgaben, postgres, 0.0.0.0, ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1
I spun up the database in a different container and tried to connect. While I could connect with DBeaver, I was not able to connect to the DB via #net application.
However, the error indicated that Entity.Framework does not support local db on this system (MAC macOS Monterey).
This is the reason I ended up specifying the docker compose in the hope that when both containers are started up from the same compose up run I could easily communicate.
I tried different Host variants such as specifying a URL for connection.

I expected
That the DB is connecting on the specified service name of the container with port 5432. I expected that the local DB can be written to by Entity.Framework.

I guess it is unable to resolve the hostname, for solving it you might want to look into the networking of the containers / stack. It should work with localhost on that port or the internal ip of the docker network though.

Your container name is automatically set to ausgabenapp-postgres.ausgaben-1 as is expected behavior. The container names may vary unless you set it to a specific value. If you want your container name to always be the same, set container_name to something you would want.
Docs
For example
postgres.ausgaben:
    image: postgres:latest
    container_name: postgres_ausgaben

